# How do you replicate this box-shadow effect?

Tags: css, box-shadow

This is my first year in CSS and I'm trying to replicate this box-shadow effect I found on Udemy:

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

I'm trying my best to replicate this effect and this is the closet I've gotten:

```css
#box {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 14px 14px -11px rgba(245,245,245,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 14px 14px -11px rgba(245,245,245,1);
box-shadow: 3px 14px 14px -11px rgba(245,245,245,1);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  }

body {
  background: black;
  
  }
```

```html
<div id='box'> Hi </div>
```

**How would you achieve this box-shadow effect?**

---

*Thanks! I solved the problem. After the fact, I discovered how Udemy solves this problem:*

```
#A_16 {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(73, 133, 184);
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 358px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(73, 133, 184);
    perspective-origin: 179px 17px;
    transform-origin: 179px 17px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(rgba(244, 244, 244, 0), rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.952941), rgb(244, 244, 244)) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(73, 133, 184);
    font: normal normal bold normal 15px / 24px 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(73, 133, 184) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The box-shadow property supports a keyword called "inset" for box-shadow inside a box. E.g. `box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 5px 5px hsl(0, 0%, 90%);`

(btw, no need for the prefixes, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow )

HOWEVER, the effect is more likely a linear-gradient background effect with a element positioned absolutely at the bottom but overlaying the clipped content.

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    height: 5.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #222;
}

.box footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #eee 80%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    Lorem<br>
    pork<br>
    ipsum<br>
    bacon
    <footer>READ MORE</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. If your interested, I have edited my post to show what Udemy actually did...